# Controlling HTML overflow/visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm developing a site with a bootstrap three column design, where the pagination controls need to obey the following constraints:

1. Fit in the middle column.
2. Remain a single line without wrapping to multiple lines.
3. Be responsive. I don't need "full"/"fluid" col-xs to col-xl responsive, just something that is fluid above col-md and I can implement an alternative for col-xs and col-sm.

I'm utterly unable to work out how I can get the damn thing to behave at all.

The 'base' was sort of like this:

```css
.pagination-button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- MDB core CSS -->
<link href="http://mdbootstrap.com/mdbcdn/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mdbootstrap.com/mdbcdn/mdbcdn/mdb.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-2'>
        <div class="card-panel">
          <span>Foo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-8'>
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=1"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=1"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=1">1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=2">2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=3">3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=4">4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=5">5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=6">6</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=7">7</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=8">8</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=9">9</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=10">10</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=11">11</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=12">12</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=13">13</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=14">14</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=15">15</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=16">16</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=17">17</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=18">18</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=19">19</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=20">20</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=21">21</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=22">22</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=23">23</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=24">24</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=25">25</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=26">26</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=27">27</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=28">28</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=29">29</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=30">30</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=31">31</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=32">32</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=3"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="pagination-item" href="?page=32"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-2'>
        <div class="card-panel">
          <span>Foo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I was able to clean it up into a single line:

```css
.pagination-button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.pagination {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- MDB core CSS -->
<link href="http://mdbootstrap.com/mdbcdn/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mdbootstrap.com/mdbcdn/mdbcdn/mdb.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-2'>
        <div class="card-panel">
          <span>Foo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-8'>
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li>
            <a href="?page=1"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?page=1"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=1">1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="?page=2">2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=3">3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=4">4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=5">5</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=6">6</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=7">7</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=8">8</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=9">9</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=10">10</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=11">11</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=12">12</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=13">13</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=14">14</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=15">15</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=16">16</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=17">17</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=18">18</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=19">19</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=20">20</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=21">21</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=22">22</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=23">23</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=24">24</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=25">25</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=26">26</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=27">27</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=28">28</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=29">29</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=30">30</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=31">31</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=32">32</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?page=3"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?page=32"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-2'>
        <div class="card-panel">
          <span>Foo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I clean up this list so its more responsive? 
CSS only would be great but after a few hours trying to get it working, I'm even willing to entertain JavaScript based approaches to solving this UX/UI problem I'm having.

I had the idea that I could solve it pretty easily if I could tag each `<li>` element with a priority and then add the elements to the `<ul>` in order of priority until they filled their allowed width, but I'm at a loss as to how to implementing something like this well and avoid all the usual browser edge cases, and I'd be throwing CSS out the window to do it, I'm still hoping their is a simpler CSS based answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, .pagination isn't displayed as inline-flex. Bootstrap uses the class too and makes it inline-block. Change .pagination to ul.pagination so your CSS will be picked (since it's more specific).
This will force all the list items in one row.

Depending on what u want, u could give the ul a max-width and work with overflow-x:scroll; in your CSS. You will probably have to add in a width:100%; for your ul.pagination.

Comment: changing `.pagination` to `ul.pagination` doesn't change anything, its the same as my second code snippet. Explaining (and prefferably demonstrating) how `width`, `max-width` and `overflow-x:scroll` would fix the issue, would make this a much more useful answer. Also "Depending on what u want" (sic) - Was I not clear enough with my 3 goals? should I be elaborating on what I want further, since I do have a clear goal here and tried to convey it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasn't specific enough. I've put my suggestions in the snippet below. (Check the ul.pagination CSS block)
It fits the middle column, and stays on one line.

The depending on what u want part is mainly regarding responsive, there are several ways to do this. This is a design/interaction question. I've suggested overflow-x: scroll; for this.

```css
.pagination-button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
ul.pagination {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- MDB core CSS -->
<link href="http://mdbootstrap.com/mdbcdn/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mdbootstrap.com/mdbcdn/mdbcdn/mdb.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-2'>
        <div class="card-panel">
          <span>Foo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-8'>
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li>
            <a href="?page=1"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?page=1"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=1">1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="?page=2">2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=3">3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=4">4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=5">5</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=6">6</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=7">7</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=8">8</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=9">9</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=10">10</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=11">11</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=12">12</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=13">13</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=14">14</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=15">15</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=16">16</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=17">17</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=18">18</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=19">19</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=20">20</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=21">21</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=22">22</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=23">23</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=24">24</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=25">25</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=26">26</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=27">27</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=28">28</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=29">29</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=30">30</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=31">31</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="?page=32">32</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?page=3"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="?page=32"><i style="font-size: 2em" class="pagination-button fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-2'>
        <div class="card-panel">
          <span>Foo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```